# create a spinner for my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web form which the user needs to submit to the server. The server response may take seconds. So I want to show the user a spinner, such that all other fields are grayed and the user make any changes in the webform and in the center I have a spinner which keeps rotating.. Please help me in how should I proceed..

Comment: Aren't we a little too prompt to close questions those days ? This isn't a perfect question and OP didn't really know what his question implies but we can't limit our help to people not really needing it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my complete solution, using ajax to send the query (you can't have a spinner if you leave the page by using a standard form post) :

```
loading = {
    count: 0
};

loading.finish = function() {
    this.count--;
    if (this.count==0) this.$div.hide();
};

// 
loading.start = function() {
    this.count++;
    if (!this.$div) {
        var html = '<div style="position: fixed;z-index:100;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;background: black;opacity: 0.6;">';
        html += '<table width=100% height=100%>';
        html += '<tr><td align=center valign=middle>';
        html += '<img src=img/loading.gif>';
        html += '</td></tr>';
        html += '</table></div>';
        this.$div=$(html);
        this.$div.prependTo('body');
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (loading.count>0) loading.$div.show();
    }, 500);
};

// the function to call
askUrl = function(url, success) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                success(msg);
            }
            loading.finish();
        }
    };
    loading.start();
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
};
```

If you call askUrl and the servers doesn't answer in 500 ms, the screen is greyed and a spinner is displayed.

I got my gif spinner [here](http://ajaxload.info/).

Comment: @webarto -1 for not using jquery ? That's a first for me. And that's a little strange as *I use* jquery.

Comment: @dystroy http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/155197

Comment: @PeeHaa OK, understood. But given that I use jquery as was requested in question, this gets a little too meta...

Comment: @webarto a personal notice : the link from your SO profile to your careers profile is dead.

Comment: @dystroy http://careers.stackoverflow.com/webarto yeah, thanks. I actually +1 for not using jQuery in this case, maybe the comment was unnecessary but it referred to what PeeHaa linked.